# Python 2.7: While loop, can't break out

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, while-loop

I'm new to programming and to this website so I hope I can clarify what I'm trying to do. I have a loop I'm trying to break out of if I send the string quit. It seems to just keep going. Please help!

```
import socket
Home = '10.0.0.5' #ipaddr
Port = 10000 #port 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((Home, Port)) 
s.send('Hey it works!') 
while True:
    data = s.recv(1024) 
    print data
    if data == 'quit': 
        break
```

I'm able to send and receive messages just fine, but when I send quit, or 'quit' it just keeps going. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: @heinst why? That doesn't make any sense -- `break` will exit the `while` loop and exit with status 0 (like it should)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to break out of while loop in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594522/how-to-break-out-of-while-loop-in-python)

Comment: I'd recommend doing `print repr(data)` and seeing what gets sent when you send `'quit'`

Comment: `data` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer definitely not a dupe of that.

Comment: @AdamSmith I went ahead with your recommendation of using print repr(data). The output was 'quit\n', I changed it from quit to the new output and it works fine. Thank you sir!

Comment: @Carson Sounds like your server is sending back the newline from you hitting `Enter` after the message. Try just doing `data = s.recv(1024).strip()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `while`-`break`- logic is fine. Part one of the problem is in the `s.recv(1024)` call, which (depending on the socket settings) may block until that many bytes arrived, see http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv:

> If no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait for
>   a message to arrive, unless the socket is nonblocking

Also, and this is part two of the problem, if you try to send **messages** through your connection, you need to invent a communication protocol that delimits messages. Otherwise `data` will never be just `'quit'`.

So, either deal with all the implications a byte stream has and learn about how system calls like `recv` behave, or use a higher-level messaging library that hides all these details from you.

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for taking the time to help me with my problem. It seems that I have a temporary fix from another user. He told me to check the output of the print repr(data), it was 'quit\n', I changed it to that and it worked fine. Can you recommend a higher level library I might be interested in the future or point me to a place where I can find one? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Python `recv` takes extra special care to wait until all the data requested is available. You can use `os.fdopen(s.fileno())` though to get a `file` object, and then use normal `read` and `write` functions on the socket.

Comment: "Python recv takes extra special care to wait until all the data requested is available." -- that is not true. Python's `s.recv()` is a leightweight wrapper around the `recv()` system call. It entirely depends on the socket settings when this function returns. Socket options like `SO_RCVLOWAT` are of importance here. So, just by seeing `a = s.recv(N)`, one must not assume that `a` is of length `N`, even if no error occurred. The argument is called `bufsize` for a reason, is not a requested length.

Comment: After receiving a "quit" message, the recv call would return if it weren't waiting for N characters. The middle ground between waiting for a full buffer and running a spinning loop is to actually use the `file()` methods.

Comment: I am just wondering what this "extra special care" is what you were talking about.

Comment: That extra special care where python waits for a full buffer despite what the underlying `read` function would normally do, as evidenced by this example and basically every python socket program ever written.

Comment: We are on the same page here, in general, I have said the same in my answer but without letting it sound like a guarantee. Also the Python docs do not guarantee what you are saying. This is still system-dependent. I have just verified myself that on Linux you can easily call `conn.recv(100)` and have it return just 4 bytes. On Linux, the default for `SO_RCVLOWAT` is 1, so this makes sense. I do not know what "special care" you are talking about unless you show some code.

Comment: "as evidenced by this example" is the wrong argument here. Client: `s.sendall("abcd");time.sleep(5);s.close()` -- Server: `conn, addr = s.accept(); print conn.recv(100)` -- this server *immediately* prints `abcd`.

Comment: It blocked indefinitely for me when I ran it, so "as evidenced by this example" and also every other bit of Python socket code I've worked with is exactly the right argument here.

Comment: All I was saying is that this is system-dependent and therefore there is no guaranteed behavior. You should appreciate this. I ran the example with Python 2.7 on Linux 3.16.

Comment: And what you should appreciate is that I've tried it for years on many systems and have never seen it behave any other way, regardless of guarantees made by Python or you or anyone else.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/socketmodule.c, at `sock_recv_guts()`. Only on OpenVMS it has a loop keeping track of `remaining` bytes. On other platforms, it calls the system call like this: `outlen = recv(s->sock_fd, cbuf, len, flags);` and then returns `outlen`. The `sock_recv` function (which corresponds to the socket module's `recv()` method) is entirely fine with `outlen != recvlen` and comments "We did not read as many bytes as we anticipated", and finally just returns the buffer. I hope my Linux 3.16 test case and code convince you more than your memories.

Comment: Sorry, still not convinced, because even though you're pulling up code that behaves differently, both the question and all the code I've ever written (even this morning) behave exactly unlike what you're writing here. Sorry. And that's exactly what "no guarantees" means. You just don't know, so you have to work in the most pessimistic behavior. In this case, it's blocking until N characters are received.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to decode the received value into a string. You may do something like

```
if data.decode("UTF-8") == 'quit':
   break
```

Comment: He is not using unicode literals (this is Python 2.7), so this is not a problem here.