# How to exit a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, user-input

I'm asking input from the user and wanted to check if he used the right letters to continue, I've wrote this code, but even when I write "y" or "n", it doesn't exit the loop, and I have no idea why:

```
while True:
    start = input("Want to start? (Y/n) ").lower()
    if start != 'y' or 'n':
        print("letter not accepted! Please write 'Y' to start or 'N' to exit!\n")
    else:
        break

if start == "y":
    separate(players)
else:
    print("Goodbye!")
```

Comment: Check if this helps :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594522/how-to-break-out-of-while-loop-in-python

Comment: break is fine. You have an infinite loop, though

Comment: don't try natural language experiments with python...

Comment: `if start not in ('y', 'n')` is more readable, by the way